# Workflow: send notification before due date

Tags: workflow, notifications

I'm an inexperienced SP user and need have created a workflow.

I created a site containing Libraries. All the Libraries contain the same new fields, which I created at the Site level.

I need a workflow that will send an email to the person named in the Point of Contact field if the `Contract End Date` is `90 days` from the `current date`.

The email should say something like " `your document is due to expire in 90 days. Please.....`"

I'm using Sharepoint 2013/Office365

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow and let it automatically start on Item Add event.

Inside the workflow use Calculate action to find out the date the notification is suppose to be sent.

Now you can use Wait or Pause activity so that the workflow will wait

Next add a sent email action..

Comment: Hi. I don't know how to do this. All the instructions I have found refer to a Data Source called **Workflow Context** (which I can see) and then a Field from source called **Association: Item Start on Creation** (which I don't have available in the dropdown list). I created a workflow
**If Current Item:Reminder Date equals Today**
   **Email [the name of the person selected from SharePoint/AD]**
I can see the workflow running but no email is coming through. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to explore document retention policies for this.

In this feature, you can apply a retention policy to documents and design rules and stages as per your requirements.

For more details refer below links ->

- [Link1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-document-deletion-policies-55e8d858-f278-482b-a198-2e62d6a2e6e5)
- [Link2](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-information-management-policies-63a0b501-ba59-44b7-a35c-999f3be057b2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)